# Does Protractor JS works for native mobile apps

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, automated-tests, webdriver-io

I kind of think that answer of this question would be `No` by going through [Protractor issue 1798](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1798#issuecomment-74405588) and [Protractor vs Webdriver-IO](http://www.webdriverjs.com/protractor-vs-webdriverio-vs-nightwatch/) comparisions.

I want to write automated tests cases for a hybrid mobile app in **JavaScript** which will run on [Appium](http://appium.io/).

Currently I have both [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/) and [Appium](http://appium.io/) configured in same project to run those `End-to-End` test cases, and they work.

**Problems are** that,

1. I have to write separate test cases for each of them.
2. Cases should also work on mobile devices(Android and iOS) and protractor doesn't support native apps tests.

Situation is, I am more comfortable with Protractor's settings in my current project than [Webdriver-IO](http://webdriver.io) which Appium uses (just a personal preference).

**Question-**

1. Is there a way of using only Protractor while writing test cases which would work using Appium and work perfectly on Devices/Emulators?

I am also open for any suggestion(s).

If answer remains `No`, I will change my codes to only use WebdriverIO in order to keep my test cases reusable and only once.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is still `NO` protractor currently does not have support for mobile native apps but you can use it for automating browsers in your mobile.

Better use [WebdriverIO](http://webdriver.io/) but it also has its own limitations, please do check its changelog and github issues before deciding it as your webdriver framework.